# Woocommerce - how to display the grouped product that a simple product belongs to on it's single product page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce site where several of my simple products are also part of grouped products. We don't mind selling these individually or as a set, so grouped products are perfect for what we're doing. However, we'd like to add extra emphasis on a product page when that a product is part of a group, ideally with a link to the grouped product.

So it's a two part question: How would I test to see if a simple product is part of a group on it's single page?  And is there a way to then get and display the grouped product, separately from "related products"?

Thanks very much!

Comment: I *think* that a grouped product is just the `post_parent` for items that are in the group. so on the single product page if `global $post; if( $post->post_parent != 0 ){ echo 'is part of a group'; }` Sorry about the code in the comments. I loathe that, but don't have time to test a full answer right now.

Comment: Awesome - that does it..!!  Interesting to note that it needs to use global $post - I had been trying almost the same thing with the global $product - (shows that I don't have a full grasp on woocommerce just yet).  Thank you so much, this is tremendously helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I should mark this as answered - helgatheviking had it right - a grouped product is the post_parent of the single product page, using the global $post variable - this works to test for a grouped product on the single product page:

```
    global $post; 

    if( $post->post_parent != 0 ){ 
       echo 'is part of a group'; 
    }
```

Thanks again helgatheviking!

Answer (score 0):

Hi this post really helped me out so I hope this helps you.....

```
function parent_permalink_button() {
   global $post; 
   if( $post->post_parent != 0 ){ 
       $permalink = get_permalink($post->post_parent);
       echo '<a class="button" href="'.$permalink.'">Link to Parent</a>';
   }
}
```